# javascript on click loading wrong class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So I have a calendar with events on it. If theres an event this is the PHP:

```
echo'<td title="Poste: '.$row[field].'<br/><br/>You start at <b>'.$row[start].'</b><br/>'.$breaks.'<br/>You finish at <b>'.$row[end].'</b><br/><br/>Total hours this week: <b>'.$totalweekhours.'</b>" data-container="body" class="full '.$style.' hidden-xs">'.$day.'</span></br></br>'.$shifttime.'</td>';
```

as you can see the class would contain "full" when I view it on a console it appears as:

```
class="full  hidden-xs"
```

When empty:

```
echo'<td data-event="'.$currentDay.'" class="empty'.$style.' hidden-xs">'.$day .'</br></br></br>&nbsp;</td>';
```

and on the console:

```
class="empty hidden-xs"
```

And now my javascript:

```
$('.empty').on('click', function(){
    var event = $(this).find('a').data('event');
    var choosen_date = $(this).data('event');
    $('#event-data').val(choosen_date);
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
$('.full').on('click', function(){
    var event = $(this).find('a').data('event');
    var choosen_date = $(this).data('event');
    $('#event-data').val(choosen_date);
    $('.modal-body').load('test2.php',function(result){
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
});
```

So when clicking on an event that is full it should load a modal with the contents of test2.php and when clicking on a date without an event it SHOULD open the modal with the normal contents of the modal. However whichever I click it loads test2.php. Anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: `.find('a')` makes it look like the click is happening on an `<a>`, but I don't see you cancelling the event anywhere, so it will always continue through to the _href_.

Comment: Where is the `<a>` tag in all this? You reference it in your js but I don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the normal contents of the modal is what you think it is. try just putting a

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

at the bottom of your script, and see what happens. It is possible you are setting the contents incorrectly somewhere else. Another good debugging technique is to add console.log statements to your two callbacks. so add `console.log("empty")` and `console.log("full")` to your two callbacks. See which fires. Maybe your selector is not specific enough.

Good luck!